# Ensuring an image map does not overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am developing a site as shown below:

[image]

This section of the website will be 100% of the height and width of the window. You can hover and click on the images to bring a modal up with more information. It will also apply an opacity to the individual pictures when you hover over them.

To achieve this effect, I had to have the image in a tag instead of using background image css, I also have an image map absolutely positioned ontop of it to provide the roll over opacity effects, and to also make them clickable.

Everything mostly works fine, however I am finding it especially difficult to make it responsive and was hoping to find a way to ensure the desk always appears in the window and does not over flow. At the moment I have had to adjust the right and left css to nudge it, but it doesn't seem to work very well.

[image]

Basically I want it so it scales down, but never crops inside the red box.

Is there any way I could achieve this?

Comment: make each img `position: relative` place them with % and not with pixels. also, give them height and width in % only

Comment: I only have the image of the desk, and the image map, both are set to: height: 130%; width: auto; position: relative; bottom: 30%; right: -2%; Making them both the same makes them scale together.

Comment: can you publish your code? or fiddle if possible?

Comment: It is still a work in progress: http://176.32.230.44/testytestytesty.com/index.html

Comment: Well I haven't looked at it yet. But a few things I can tell you - I've once made a single page app that had a responsive bg and on it floating divs that had to respond to the bg image while making the window smaller.
What I've done - made a container and give it background and then give it `center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
I've done the **same** to the floating divs, while making them relative position and placed them with %

Comment: I cannot set a background image to 100% 100% because it distorts the image of the desk.